# Doctrine Extension bug with APCu : "ORM TreeListener does not support tree type:"

Tags: php, caching, symfony, doctrine, apc

I have a tree type entity configured with annotation in "nested" tree type.

I activated PHP5.5 APCu extension, and after some time, a weird exceptions is throwned: 

`ORM TreeListener does not support tree type:`

(with nothing after the "type:")

The website works fine some hours and does this after.

If I clear the APCu cache, all works fine for several hours.

Here is the stacktrace :

```
Stacktrace (most recent call first):

File "[...]/vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/lib/Gedmo/Tree/TreeListener.php", line 84, in getStrategy
  throw new \Gedmo\Exception\InvalidArgumentException($managerName." TreeListener does not support tree type: {$config['strategy']}");
File "[...]/vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/lib/Gedmo/Tree/Entity/Repository/NestedTreeRepository.php", line 846, in validate
  return $this->listener->getStrategy($this->_em, $this->getClassMetadata()->name)->getName() === Strategy::NESTED;
File "[...]/vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/lib/Gedmo/Tree/Entity/Repository/AbstractTreeRepository.php", line 52, in __construct
  if (!$this->validate()) {
File "[...]/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php", line 689, in getRepository
  $repository = new $repositoryClassName($this, $metadata);
File "[...]/app/cache/prod/jms_diextra/doctrine/EntityManager_520e1bbfadf9e.php", line 180, in getRepository
  $repository = $this->delegate->getRepository($className);
File "[...]/src/Mapado/ActivityFrontBundle/Controller/ActivityController.php", line 85, in viewAction
  $rubricRepo = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager('rubric')->getRepository('MapadoRubric:Rubric');
File "[...]/app/bootstrap.php.cache", line 2805, in handleRaw
  $response = call_user_func_array($controller, $arguments);
File "[...]/app/bootstrap.php.cache", line 2779, in handle
  return $this->handleRaw($request, $type);
File "[...]/app/bootstrap.php.cache", line 2908, in handle
  $response = parent::handle($request, $type, $catch);
File "[...]/app/bootstrap.php.cache", line 2210, in handle
  return $this->getHttpKernel()->handle($request, $type, $catch);
File "[...]/web/app.php", line 22, in null
  $response = $kernel->handle($request);
```

Do you have some hint that could help me resolve this bug ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faced the same problem.
See this https://github.com/krakjoe/apcu/issues/35
Just set options apc.serializer to php

Comment: After a day of use, it seems to be stable, the bug is not back. Thank you !